# data backup and recovery in hadoop 2.2.0

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I am new to Hadoop and much interested in Hadoop Administration,so i tried to install Hadoop 2.2.0 in Ubuntu 12.04 as pseudo distributed mode and installed successfully and run some example jar files also ,now i am trying learn further ,trying to learn data back up and recovery part now,can anyone tell ways to take data back back up and recovery it in hadoop 2.2.0 ,and also please suggest any good books for Hadoop Adminstration and steps to learn Hadoop Adminstration.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: A good book is called "Hadoop Operations" from O'Reilly, but for the rest, can you specify what exact problem are you having and what steps you've tried so far?  Your question as is too open ended and not on topic for Stack Overflow (which is focused on development and not administration).

Answer (score 1):

There is no classic backup and recovery functionality in Hadoop.  There are several reasons for this:

- HDFS uses block level replication for data protection via redundancy.
- HDFS scales out massively in size, and it is becoming more economic to backup to disk, rather than tape.
- The size of "Big Data" doesn't lend itself to being easily backed up.

Instead of backups, Hadoop uses data replication.  Internally, it creates multiple copies of each block of data (by default, 3 copies).  It also has a function called 'distcp', which allows you to replicate copies of data between clusters.  This is what's typically done for "backups" by most Hadoop operators.

Some companies, like Cloudera, are incorporating the distcp tool into creating a 'backup' or 'replication' service for their distribution of Hadoop.  It operates against a specific directory in HDFS, and replicates it to another cluster.

If you really wanted to create a backup service for Hadoop, you can create one manually yourself.  You would need some mechanism of accessing the data (NFS gateway, webFS, etc), and could then use tape libraries, VTLs, etc. to create backups.